# Weird bug with border:0 / none css

Tags: html, css

i have a weird bug with my css

```css
#box1 {
  border:2px solid #CC9933;
  padding:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px 0;
  border-radius:10px ;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: auto;
}

#box1 label {
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

#box1 span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#box1 span input {
  width: 100%;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:solid 1px #000;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  <form>
    <div>
      <label> Nom de la société </label>
      <span><input type="text" value=""></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label> Adresse </label>
      <span><input type="text" value=""></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I won't show all the HTML because it is the same structure.
The thing is that in my web browser it looks like this :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cEQfY0E.jpg]

However, this is how it should looks like :
(this is the same code !)

http://jsfiddle.net/8vsyxtys/

Comment: You have a `float` that you aren't `clear`ing. The container `<div>` elements should have `clear:left`.

Comment: If you can't reproduce it, how can we debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely the float:left.

Try adding a clear div after each:

css would be: .clear { clear:both; height: 1px; }

```css
#box1 {
border:2px solid #CC9933;
padding:5px;
-moz-border-radius:10px 0;
-webkit-border-radius:10px 0;
border-radius:10px ;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: auto;
}

#box1 label {
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

#box1 span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#box1 span input {
    width: 100%;
    border:none;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #000;
    outline:none;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
  height: 1px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="box1">
 <form>
  <div>
    <label> Nom de la société </label>
      <span><input type="text" value=""></span>
  </div>
  <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
  <div>
    <label> Adresse </label>
      <span><input type="text" value=""></span>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```